# searching for specific recipients in my email then notify me when a new message arrives in python

Tags: python, email

I am trying to receive a text when I receive a new email from a certain email address such as `johndoe@gmail.com`. I got it to work where I can send myself a text with using my email. I am struggling to figure out how to set it up to search for a specific email and to have it constantly checking every 15 minutes.

```
import smtplib

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('EMAIL@gmail.com', 'PASSWORD')
smtpObj.sendmail('EMAIL@gmail.com', 
'phoneNumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com',
                     'You have received an email from john doe')
{}
smtpObj.quit()

# When receives email from johndoe@gmail.com text my phone number

# Start an infinite loop that checks email and carries out instructions.


    # Wait 15 minutes before checking again
```

---UPDATE
I got a few parts to work but I'm struggling with how to get the cronTab to work because i think that would be more of what I'm trying to do with this program. I got it to find a specific email but how would i set it up to just notify me that i have received a new email from the specific sender since the last check and then mark it as read or something so i do not keep getting notified about that email. I also just want it to check the current date and not all my previous emails so it stays current.

```
import smtplib, imaplib, pprint, imapclient, pyzmail, datetime

import time

import crontab


cron = Crontab()
starttime = time.time()
now = datetime.datetime.now()

job = cron.new(command='/usr/bin/echo')

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtpObj.ehlo()
    smtpObj.starttls()
    smtpObj.login('userName@gmail.com', 'Password')
    smtpObj.sendmail('userName@gmail.com', 'phoneNum@messaging.sprintpcs.com',
                     'Subject: Received Email:')
    {}
    smtpObj.quit()

    # When recieves email from johndoe@gmail.com text my phone number


    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login('userName@gmail.com', 'Password')
    mail.list()
    # Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
    mail.select("inbox")  # connect to inbox.

    result, data = mail.search(now.day, '(FROM "userName" SUBJECT "Test")')

    ids = data[0]  # data is a list.
    id_list = ids.split()  # ids is a space separated string
    latest_email_id = id_list[0]  # get the latest



    result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")  # fetch the email body (RFC822)             for the given ID

    raw_email = data[0][1]  # here's the body, which is raw text of the whole email
    # including headers and alternate payloads

    pprint.pprint(raw_email)

    # Start an infinite loop that checks email and carries out instructions.


    # Wait 15 minutes before checking again
    job.minute.every(15)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know where your email is *stored*.

Comment: It might make more sense to run your script as a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) rather than trying to have your script "constantly checking every 15 minutes".